# How to get static context in FlutterPlugin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I want to set static get and set context method in FlutterPlugin, how should I implement it in kotlin way?

```
class FlutterPushPlugin : FlutterPlugin {
    private var context: Context? = null

    fun getContext(): Context? {
        return this.context
    }

    fun setContext(context: Context?) {
        this.context = context
    }
}

// In another class
FlutterPushPlugin.getContext  // return the context property in FlutterPushPlugin
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a companion object or object itself to do the job, but it is strongly **not** recommended to put context in static objects as this could cause memory leaks. But if you do, you have to be very careful how you use them. Now for your question:

```
object StaticContext {
    var context: Context? = null
}
```

Or

```
class FlutterPushPlugin : FlutterPlugin {

    companion object {
        var context: Context? = null
    }
}
```

There is no need for getters and setters as `Kotlin` generates them when using `var`.